# Is there any point to keep the CSCE after the FCC registers the upgrade?

Tags: united-states, legal, license, fcc

Is there any point to keeping the CSCE form after the FCC registers the exam/upgrade in its database? I'm trying to go paperless in my old age and if there's no reason not to have the paper copy, into the shredder it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shred it.

The only time where such paperwork proved valuable was from the days of "Tech Plus" (passed written element 3A and 5 WPM code).  The FCC eventually reverted Tech Plus to Tech licenses. When the code requirement for General was dropped, former Tech Plus licensees could get "automatic" upgrades  to General if they could show paper proof of their former status. This was back in the days when paper, not bits, mattered.

Comment: A Tech Plus license was issued to a candidate who passed the Novice written, Novice 5 WPM Code, and Tech written. The Tech Plus included both Novice HF privileges and Tech VHF/UHF privileges.  Hence "Tech Plus HF". Then General element had nothing to to with the Tech Plus license class in that era.  In pre 1987 the Technician written included the General written.  It was that which gave us all the "Grandfather Generals" for Techs licensed prior to 1987, when code was later dropped all together.

Comment: Certainly.  Another time a CSCE could come into play was, for example, and this is my story: In 1994 at my first license test session I tested and passed all 5 (Novice, Tech, General, Advance, Extra) written elements and 5WPM CW so my initial license was Tech Plus.  Then a couple of months later I passed 13WPM CW.  That along with my Tech Plus license and my CSCEs for General and Advanced from 2 months before got me the upgrade to Advanced.  None of these apply anymore because each element passed grants you a new license class.